# Golang claims my method is undefined, but it's RIGHT THERE

Tags: go

I'm having trouble understanding why Go isn't recognizing one singular method from outside of its package. This isn't happening with any other methods used outside of their packages. I am rather new to Go, so I'm wondering if there is some aspect of scope that I'm just missing.

`database.go`:

```
package database

type Database struct {
    fileString    string
}
```

`db-table-person.go`:

```
package database

import (
    "context"
)

type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Age     int
}

func (db *Database) AddPerson(ctx context.Context, person *Person) error {
   // code to add a person to a database
}
```

`get-objects-from-file.go`:

```
package myapp

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "ioutil"
    
    database "path/to/database/package/that/works/for/every/other/database/method"
)

type BundleOfObjects struct {
    People []database.People
    Dogs   []database.Dogs
}

func LoadObjectsFromFile(filename string) (objects BundleOfObjects) {
    jsonFile, _ := os.Open(filename)
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    bytevalue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var objects BundleOfObjects

    _ = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &BundleOfObjects)

    return BundleOfObjects
}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    database "path/to/database/package/that/works/for/every/other/method/in/the/database/package/"
    myapp "path/to/myapp/that/works/for/every/other/method/in/myapp"
)

func main() {
    filename := "myfile.json"

    bundleOfObjects := myapp.LoadObjectsFromFile(filename)

    for _, p := range bundleOfObjects.People {
        database.AddPerson(context.Background(), p)
    }
}
```

I get the following error referencing the call to `AddPerson` in `main.go`: `undefined: database.AddPerson`

I cannot stress enough that I have successfully shared many methods throughout these three packages with zero issues whatsoever, all seemingly using this exact same process. What am I missing?

Comment: `database` is a package name in `main.go`, where do you define the object of type `database.Database` on which you'll call the `AddPerson` method? You're calling a method on the package.

Comment: Benjamin is correct.  You need to make a Database object and then call the object method on that instantiated struct.

Answer (score 1):

As always, just a minute or two after posting my question, the answer becomes apparent. The problem is that `AddPerson()` is a method, not just a function without a receiver. It needs to be called on an existing instance of `Database.` So in `main.go`, I would need to create a database instance first and then use it to call `AddPerson().` Like so:

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    database "path/to/database/package/that/works/for/every/other/method/in/the/database/package/"
    myapp "path/to/myapp/that/works/for/every/other/method/in/myapp"
)

func main() {
    filename := "myfile.json"
    db := database.Database{fileString: "my-database.db"}


    bundleOfObjects := myapp.LoadObjectsFromFile(filename)

    for _, p := range bundleOfObjects.People {
        db.AddPerson(context.Background(), p)
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanHall good catch! I'll update.